# How to reference script files in webpack deploy?

Tags: bash, reactjs, webpack, electron, spawn

I am using webpack and electron and while I can reference my script files fine locally (app/scripts/scriptname.sh), when it comes to the production deploy, I get an error: `Can't open app/components/scripts/scriptname.sh`.

It's unclear to me if this is an electron-dependent issue or a webpack-issue.

I am running these using node child_process as:

`var ls = spawn('sh', ['app/components/scripts/scriptname.sh']);`

I don't necessarily need the scripts to be in their own folder it would just be helpful.

Comment: Do not just provide full path from the current directory, try providing the absolute path from the base folder

Comment: Can you give me an example? I've tried using `./scripts/` and this hasn't worked either.

Comment: if the script full path is for example from `/home/foobar/foldername/app/components/scripts/scriptname.sh`, try giving this absolute path, than just `app/components/scripts/scriptname.sh`

Comment: Surely there is a way to do this without referencing the computer / user name and the `home` folder? Given that I'd like to be using this app on different computers I don't think this is the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the complete absolute path to the script. To do that you can use the [app.getAppPath()](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/app.md#appgetapppath) API of electron

> app.getAppPath()
>
> Returns String - The current application directory.

So your code would be something like:

```
var scriptAbsolutePath = app.getAppPath() + '/app/components/scripts/scriptname.sh'; 
var ls = spawn('sh', [scriptAbsolutePath]);
```

You can also have a look at [app.getPath(name)](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/app.md#appgetpathname) API if it satisfies your particular requirement.

Comment: I think this is in the right direction. I am using `const {app} = require('electron');` but when I run the app, I'm receiving a `cannot read property 'getAppPath' of undefined` error. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think the curly braces way of importing named modules is yet supported. You can do the following. const electron = require('electron'); const app = electron.app;

Comment: I did end up finding app through `require('electron').remote.app` however it isn't quite giving me what I'd expect... Surely there is some way of "including" or "importing" my script files to be compiled within the Electron app without needing to reference them outside of the compiled app?